# Select max date even if it's null?

Tags: mysql, date

I have an issue with selecting the MAX date for a price expiration in my table. 
The table stores historical data and if no date is set for the last week it searches for the MAX date to auto-populate the price expiration.

My issue is, if I update the price expiration to be NULL (sometimes prices won't expire) then when I check to get the last price expiration date I keep getting the date before the NULL entry. What I want is the NULL date if that is the newest entry.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers_view_items` (
`cid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item` varchar(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'item number from dProduce',
  `custno` varchar(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'customer number from dProduce',
  `week_of` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'week for pricing this was saved as',
  `cost` double(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'current cost when this was saved',
  `market_price` double(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'current market price when this was saved',
  `discount` double(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'discount that was applied to get the price for history',
  `current_margin` double(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'current margin for history',
  `avg_margin` double(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'average margin for history',
  `volume` double(12,3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'volume',
  `price` double(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Price set for customer item',
  `priceexp` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Date price expires',
  `saved_on` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Datetime of save',
  `saved_by` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'user id that saved',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `custno_item_weekof` (`custno`,`item`,`week_of`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores the customer items data from customer view items sect' AUTO_INCREMENT=629 ;
```

The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT 
    custno,
    item, 
    price, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(priceexp) as priceexp 
FROM `customers_view_items` 
WHERE custno = 'LASP' 
ORDER BY `week_of` DESC
```

This gives me the rows of the data but I cannot seem how to fetch just the latest entry.

If I do `MAX(priceexp)` I just get the highest price expiration (as expected)

I assume I need to do a sub-query to get the result I need but I am lost right now.

I added the `cid` to identify the latest entry but I think the `week_of` would work too (and is preferred actually)

Any push in the right direction would help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: LIMIT 1? Check it out. Read the manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax.html)

Comment: Limit 1 would work if I was using a per ITEM query. My example had the item conditional... I meant to remove that as my actual query is not on a per item basis but a per customer. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use the subquery to pull the newest record first.

```
select a.custno, a.item, a.price, unix_timestamp(a.priceexp) priceexp
from customers_view_items a
join (
  select custno, item, max(week_of) week_of
  from customers_view_items
  group by custno, item) b on a.custno = b.custno and a.item = b.item and a.week_of = b.week_of;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get what I needed by tweaking this query.